# Inner polygon approximation

Tags: symbolic, geometry, computational-geometry, algebraic-manipulation, polygons

Suppose you want to perform an inner approximation of a planar semialgebraic set by a finite set of polygons. The following is a quick way to yield an approximation but I am not convinced that it is in fact an inner approximation.

Let's consider the following example.

```
reg = (7/4 + x)^2 + (-(9/4) + y)^2 < 1/9 || (-(9/4) + x)^2 + (-(9/4) + y)^2 < 1/9 ||
      (x^2 + y^2 < 25 && (-2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 >= 1 &&
      (2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 >= 1 && (x^2 + (1 + y)^2 >= 5 || x^2 + (-1 + y)^2 < 9));
RegionPlot[reg, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: RegionPlot]

Next you can decompose the semialgebraic set into disjoint subsets.

```
regs = Select[List @@ BooleanConvert[reg, "ESOP"], Not[FindInstance[#, {x, y}] === {}] &]
{(-(9/4) + x)^2 + (-(9/4) + y)^2 >= 1/9 && (7/4 + x)^2 + (-(9/4) + y)^2 < 1/9 && 
 (2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 < 1 && x^2 + (-1 + y)^2 < 9,
 (-2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 >= 1 && (2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 >= 1 &&
 x^2 + (-1 + y)^2 < 9 && x^2 + y^2 < 25, 
 (-(9/4) + x)^2 + (-(9/4) + y)^2 < 1/9 && (-2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 < 1 && 
 (2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 >= 1 && x^2 + (-1 + y)^2 < 9,
 (-2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 >= 1 && (2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 >= 1 &&
 x^2 + (-1 + y)^2 >= 9 && x^2 + y^2 < 25 && x^2 + (1 + y)^2 >= 5}
RegionPlot[regs, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: RegionPlot2]

Finally, one can obtain the boundary polygons (including those representing holes) via

```
Map[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}]]["BoundaryPolygons"] &, regs] // TableForm
```

[image: Polygons]

While it is neat to be able to do this, I wonder about the following:

1. Do the resulting polygons always represent an inner approximation of the original planar semialgebraic set? I suppose not because I do not expect `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` to provide such guarantees. Moreover, `Polygon` is given in machine precision which could be another source of violating the inner approximation property.
2. How can a Boolean combination of linear forms ("linear" semialgebraic set) be obtained that is guaranteed to be an inner approximation of the original semialgebraic set (possibly not restricted to 2D if possible)?
3. Naturally, it would be desirable to have parameters for 2. to trade approximation accuracy (e.g. in terms of volume(approximation)/volume(original_set)) vs. expression size)

Comment: In 2D I would expect the approximation to be inner at every neighboring pair of boundary points for which the actual boundary is convex-outward. A second derivative test can make this determination. For other neighbor pairs, an adjustment can be made by using the tangents through those points and their point of intersection. I expect this can be coded although it will be tedious perhaps (I am not well versed in the intricacies of working with a discretized mesh).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In fact, I am also curious about completely different ways to arrive at the result, also in higher dimensions. I used the "approach" above merely to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Same idea in higher dimensions, using tangent hyperplanes wherever one or more points in a boundary mesh element are located where the boundary is not convex-outward.

Comment: For a point test to be sufficient, some assumptions are needed, I believe. One could imagine a line segment connecting two points on the boundary of the semialgebraic set and the boundary curve being partly outwards and partly inwards.

Comment: Correct. The assumption is that boundary elements are sufficiently small that this does not happen. Call it a "no wiggle" assumption. Which perhaps can be tested by bounding second derivatives over intervals between mesh segments.

Comment: With above example you should note that outermost disk isn't actually closed, which would make this problem particularly annoying to solve - unless one just limits interest to closures.